# How to add dropdowns in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

details about the questions
...........................................................................................

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<section style="background: aliceblue; width: 100%; height: 100px;" th:fragment="header">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="http://localhost:8080">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="Przejdź do strony głównej" width="80" style="padding: 10px">
        </a>
        <a style="padding: 20px" class="col-sm" th:href="@{/ordersCatalog}">Zamówienia klientów</a>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
           data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Klienci
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/listClient}">Lista klientów</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/addClient}">Dodawanie klientów</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2"
           data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Części
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink2">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@{/partsCatalog}">Katalog części</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="@{/addPart}">Dodawanie części do katalogu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <a style="padding: 20px" class="col-sm" th:href="@{/contact}">Kontakt</a>
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/cart">
            <img src="cart.png" alt="Koszyk" width="80" style="padding: 10px">
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="card-footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; background: aliceblue; width: 100%; height: 50px; "
     th:fragment="footer">
    <a href="http://localhost:8080">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Przejdź do strony głównej" width="80">
    </a>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Dropdowns don't work. I don't know how to fix it. I want to display one button with dropdowns

Title
        
    
    
    
        
            
                
            
            Zamówienia klientów
        

        
            
            Klienci

Lista klientów

Dodawanie klientów

Comment: We need some code please, and some information like the bootstrap's version you're using..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted from bootstrap docs -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Add the link above in head of your html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Add the script above on the bottom of `<body>` before the closing `</body>` tag

Button dropdown below

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Zamówienia klientów Klienci
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lista klientów</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dodawanie klientów</a>]
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried something like this. I think I have to add JS or style CSS. When i put button it doesn't happen

Comment: Check the updated code for what to style and js to add to your html file

Comment: It doesn't work. When I run snippet it works.

Comment: Run snippet where?

Comment: on stackoverflow

Comment: how are you hosting your files?

Comment: I solved this. Script should be in <section>, because I use 'th:fragment="header"'